# Why would an object disappear when switching from monocular to binocular vision?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision, microscopy

I have just used a compound binocular microscope which has an ‘eyepiece graticule’ (ruler in arbitrary units) in the right eyepiece lens.

If you close your left eye (or occlude the left lens), the graticule is clearly visible; if you open your eye (binocular vision) and look down both lens it disappears from view.

Is this an optical phenomenon or a ‘neural’ phenomenon - the latter feels more likely but I struggle to imagine the brain ignores objects which are only in one eye’s field of vision…

Comment: Well it's seems not plausible that the whole object gets hidden, but generally indeed there can be situations where you'd see an image produced mostly by one eye (or it would seem to be so). E.g. if you look at a single spot on the screen non-movingly with one eye, another being obscured with a hand to effectively close it (but keep the eyelid open as if looking), you may be able to notice after several seconds (a dozen maybe) dark regions will extend over the screen, which you'll be able to blow away by shifting the direction of look and trying to actually pay attention at what you see.